# TypeError: TypeError("object of type 'NoneType' has no len()",) while convert pdf to image

Tags: python, django, macos, imagemagick, ghostscript

I am building API which converts uploaded pdf to image based on Django REST framework, on MacOS env.
Of course, installed imagemagick and ghostscript well on the system.

Here is my code snippet.

```
from wand.image import Image 
try:
       with Image(filename=pdffile, resolution=300) as img:
                for i, page in enumerate(img.sequence):
                    filename = '{}-{}.jpg'.format(imagefilename, i + 1)
                    file ='{}/{}'.format(tmp_dir, filename)
                    Image(page).save(filename=file)
                    filelist.append(filename)
except WandException as e:
       print e
except TypeError as e:
       print e
```

But I am getting this error:

> Exception TypeError: TypeError("object of type 'NoneType' has no
>   len()",) in bound method Image.**del** of wand.image.Image:
>   (empty) ignored

At the line:

```
with Image(filename=pdffile, resolution=300) as img:
```

Here is trackback:

Internal Server Error: /api/v1/admin/upload/pdf

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Volumes/WORK/Projects/BazeanAnalytics/web-app-baz-analytics/API/data-api/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 149, in get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/Volumes/WORK/Projects/BazeanAnalytics/web-app-baz-analytics/API/data-api/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 147, in get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Volumes/WORK/Projects/BazeanAnalytics/web-app-baz-analytics/API/data-api/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py",
>   line 58, in wrapped_view
>       return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Volumes/WORK/Projects/BazeanAnalytics/web-app-baz-analytics/API/data-api/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py",
>   line 68, in view
>       return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Volumes/WORK/Projects/BazeanAnalytics/web-app-baz-analytics/API/data-api/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
>   line 466, in dispatch
>       response = self.handle_exception(exc)   File "/Volumes/WORK/Projects/BazeanAnalytics/web-app-baz-analytics/API/data-api/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
>   line 463, in dispatch
>       response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Volumes/WORK/Projects/BazeanAnalytics/web-app-baz-analytics/API/data-api/data_api/announcement/views.py",
>   line 582, in post
>       filelist = self._slice_n_convert_pdf_to_image(tmp_dir, file_obj.name)
>
> File
>   "/Volumes/WORK/Projects/BazeanAnalytics/web-app-baz-analytics/API/data-api/data_api/announcement/views.py",
>   line 557, in _slice_n_convert_pdf_to_image
>       with Image(filename=pdffile, resolution=300) as img:
>
> File
>   "/Volumes/WORK/Projects/BazeanAnalytics/web-app-baz-analytics/API/data-api/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/image.py",
>   line 2744, in **init**
>       self.read(filename=filename, resolution=resolution)
>
> File
>   "/Volumes/WORK/Projects/BazeanAnalytics/web-app-baz-analytics/API/data-api/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/image.py",
>   line 2822, in read
>       self.raise_exception()
>
> File
>   "/Volumes/WORK/Projects/BazeanAnalytics/web-app-baz-analytics/API/data-api/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/resource.py",
>   line 222, in raise_exception
>       raise e DelegateError: FailedToExecuteCommand `'gs' -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4
>   '-r300x300' 
>   '-sOutputFile=/var/folders/kl/5qf5q4x50xj2rbdp8t2prsbh0000gn/T/magick-645443wbRHI2nYLWV%d'
>   '-f/var/folders/kl/5qf5q4x50xj2rbdp8t2prsbh0000gn/T/magick-64544qCe-gNjUlDXO'
>   '-f/var/folders/kl/5qf5q4x50xj2rbdp8t2prsbh0000gn/T/magick-64544VNalr_sUZm2w''
>   (1) @ error/pdf.c/InvokePDFDelegate/292

I googled this problem, but couldn't find out correct solution. Most of them say like this:

- Re-install ImageMagick/Ghostscript.
- Check system environment path variable.

These solutions don't work for me. Have you ever faced issues like this? Have any other solutions?

Comment: What is Image here? Does it definitely work as a context manager?

Comment: @Daniel - Yeah, "Image" is the object which is in Imagemagick library. I omit one line: from wand.image import Image

Comment: Can you remove those except statements and show the whole traceback?

Comment: @Daniel - I will update post

Comment: @DanielRoseman It seems that it's ghostscript problem, but I already installed ghostscript well.

Comment: Try running the command at the end of the traceback (note that you might have to remove some quotes ) in a console, and check the output.

Comment: @CristiFati - gs is working, but can not execute the command at the end of the trackback because the files in the path in that command is temporary file.

Comment: I don't really see what you think the problem with a temporary file is. Provided the file exists for the lifetime of the Ghostscript process, then there won't be a problem. It looks to me like the Python script simply executes 'gs' and that's not in the current path, so it can't execute it. Just because you installed Ghostscript doesn't mean that your path environment variable is set to include the install directory, for the user under which your Python script runs.

Comment: @KenS - It says like this: Error: /undefinedfilename in (/var/folders/kl/5qf5q4x50xj2rbdp8t2prsbh0000gn/T/magick-80028adi9vIVrPTlX)
Anyway, 'gs' is working on console. I am not sure why imagemagick can't find gs path. I am using Django / isolated venv.

Comment: @KenS - I already added a ghostscript directory to $PATH variable like this: /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.22/bin. But it doesn't work for me yet.

Comment: The undefinedfilename error tells you the file doesn't exist. So either you have the filename wrong, or it doesn't exist at the time Ghostscript tried to read it, possibly its been deleted already. It would help if you posted the Ghostscript backtrace when discussing this. Oh, and if you got that error, then Ghostscript is working fine, that's a PostScript error. So its not the PATH, its the non-existence of the file you asked Ghostscript to process.

Comment: @KenS - Thanks. I 'd executed it in the console and it works well. But doesn't work in my code yet.

Answer (score 2):

The exception ...

> Exception TypeError: TypeError("object of type 'NoneType' has no len()",) in bound method Image.del of wand.image.Image: (empty) ignored

... is caused by wand thinking that a raster image has been loaded -- even though it was not. This `TypeError` has been resolved in future releases, but that's a symptom of the issue. The real solution is to discover *why* [ghostscript](/questions/tagged/ghostscript) failed to read/render the PDF.

> Have you ever faced issues like this?

Usually the PDF is the issue. Perhaps a malformed data-stream, or a confusing meta-tag that ghostscript/libtiff doesn't understand. Regardless of the reason, gs is exiting in a none-zero error state, and ImageMagick is rejecting the request as a delegation error.

> Have any other solutions?

1. Verify that ImageMagick can render the file as expected.

   ```
   convert -density 300x300 source.pdf output%d.png
   ```

   - Observer any warning/error messages written to stdout & stderr.
   - Use `-debug All` to see a verbose log of all actions.
2. Verify that Ghostscript can render the file as expected.

   ```
    gs -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIT -dSAFER -dBATCH \
       -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 \
       -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 -sDEVICE=pngalpha \
       -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r300x300 \
       -sOutputFile=output%d.png \
       -fsource.pdf
   ```

   - Observer any messages like above, but call `$?` immediately
     after `gs` command to verify ghostscript completed successfully by returning `0` status.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I wish you check the trackback of the error. It says it can not execute the "gs" - in spite of ghostscript is already installed. So I think the main problem is that imagemagick don't find out the ghostscript. the 2 verify solutions you mentioned above are working well.

Comment: Please focus in the line of error: DelegateError: FailedToExecuteCommand `'gs' -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r300x300' '-sOutputFile=/var/folders/kl/5qf5q4x50xj2rbdp8t2prsbh0000gn/T/magick-645443wbRHI2nYLWV%d' '-f/var/folders/kl/5qf5q4x50xj2rbdp8t2prsbh0000gn/T/magick-64544qCe-gNjUlDXO' '-f/var/folders/kl/5qf5q4x50xj2rbdp8t2prsbh0000gn/T/magick-64544VNalr_sUZm2w'' (1) @ error/pdf.c/InvokePDFDelegate/292

Comment: emcconville is correct, the problem is that your input file doesn't exist. This is only clear because in the comments above you mention that GS returns an error 'undefinedfilename' which you didn't mention anywhere else. If you ahev extra information, please share it!